# Mean and variance of max of 3 or 4 different Gaussian RVs

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, machine-learning, mathematica

I am trying to model the timing of a series of events where event $Y$ takes place right after the latest of $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$, where $n \in \{2, 3, 4\}$

For this I am assuming
$$
\begin{align}
X_i &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i)\\
Y   &= \max(X_1, ..., X_n).
\end{align}
$$

It is relatively easy to prove that the CDF is
$$
F_Y(y) = \prod_i F_{X_i}(y).
$$
From this, the PDF can be calculated via chain rule.

Since I intend to approximate $Y$ by a Gaussian distribution, I am interested in its mean and variance. Unfortunately, for the cases $n=3$ and $n=4$, I don't have any good ideas for how to tackle it.

For the case $n=2$, I used formula 10,011.3 from  [Owen](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610918008812164)  and 8.259.2 from [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123849335000084).

Using
\begin{align}
  \delta     &= \frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}}, \\
  \phi(x)    &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})
\end{align}

the mean and the variance are
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[Y] &= \frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}
                + \frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{2}\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
                + \phi(\delta)\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2} \\
  \mathrm{Var}(Y) &= \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \mathbb{E}[Y]^2 \\
                    &= \frac{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 + \mu_1^2 + \mu_2^2}{2}
                    + \frac{\sigma_1^2 - \sigma_2^2 + \mu_1^2 - \mu_2^2}{2}
                      \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
                    &\phantom{={}}
                    + \phi(\delta)(\mu_1 + \mu_2)\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}
                    - \mathbb{E}[Y]^2
\end{align}

For this simpler case of $n=2$, I tried throwing the integrals at Mathematica, but without luck (I have never used it before, so it might also be on me), therefore I didn't even try it with larger $n$.

This is very closely related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115048/on-z-max-leftx-1-x-2-dots-x-n-right-where-x-i-sim-mathcaln-mu), but I am interested in the moments of the distribution for $n=3$ and $n=4$.

Since this is in a machine-learning context, I'm also considering approximations. One such idea is to calculate $\max(X_1, X_2, X_3) = \max(\max(X_1, X_2), X_3)$ and approximate $\max(X_1, X_2)$ with a Gaussian using the calculations for $n=2$, but this will make the result depend on the order of the calculations.

Any help in getting closed form solutions or good approximations is greatly appreciated!